# Excel VBA Runtime Error: Overflow

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting an overflow error on this macro:

```
Sub searchAndCopy()

Dim wbOpen As Workbook
Set wbOpen = Workbooks("ExtractedColumns.xlsm")

Dim searchString As String
searchString = "-----------------------------------------------------------------"

Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer
lastRow = 0

Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
Set thisSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim sh As Worksheet

For i = thisSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If (thisSheet.Range("A" & i) = searchString) Then
        If lastRow = 0 Then
            lastRow = i
        Else
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Set sh = ActiveSheet
            thisSheet.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=sh.Rows("1:1")
            thisSheet.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & lastRow).Delete
            'Commenting the following code didn't affect the error, so I'm keeping them as comments until I figure it out
            'Call extractSiteColumns
            'For Each curr In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
                'If InStr(1, curr.Value, "----") > 0 Then curr.Value = ""
            'Next
            lastRow = i
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I'm almost sure that what's causing the error is in the lines before the For loop starts, because the for loop doesn't seem to execute (and I didn't change anything in it). The only thing I've been tinkering with is the reference to the "ExtractedColumns" workbook.

Any ideas of what causes this overflow error?

Comment: Try changing `i` to a Long instead of an integer.

Comment: also `lastRow As Long`. And also `For i = thisSheet.Range("A" & thisSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1` . OR, just use `With thisSheet` before the `For i` loop

Comment: Thanks! I tried both of these and there's no longer an error.